# Laravel Composer installation

Tags: php, laravel-4, wamp, composer-php, symfony-components

I have recently had to to reinstall XP since doing so I am unable to get composer to install laravel it fails at "-Installing symfony/finder (v2.4.4)" and I get an error exception
"ZipArchive::extractTo(): File exists" I have tried to install manually I have also used composer diagnose which say everything is ok  I have tried php -v all to no avail so I tried to install on a similar machine and it works fine. until I had to reinstall XP Laravel installed fine I tried google but no help there, any thoughts ?

Comment: Well the error seems to be saying that it is trying to unzip a file and save it to disk but the file already exists, and it does not expect it to and therefore errors. I assume this is a second attempt at the install. Try cleaning out the previous install and starting again.

Comment: Thank you RiggsFolly for your reply, I have tried to delete the folder but I get an error saying that the Fixtures folder is not empty the only way I can delete is to start up is safe mode, I have followed the instructions to manually install composer and still the same error I am now hoping that my other machine doesn't fail till I figure this one out

Comment: Just to keep you updated I have successfully installed Laravel but only in safe mode with network mode I think there may be a another piece of software cause my problem ?

Comment: After days of installing and reinstalling it turns out to be a corrupted windows file

Answer (score 0):

You won't get the `ZipArchive::extractTo(): File exists` error if you run the command line as an administrator.